# Sometimes can't verify CSRF token authenticity in regular web app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csrf, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a simple Rails 6 app where I use a form

```
<%= bootstrap_form_with(model: event, local: true, html: { multipart: true }) do |form| %>
```

In the generated HTML I have this is the header

```
<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="SOME TOKEN" />
```

And in the form

```
<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="SOME OTHER TOKEN" />
```

Usually all works fine, but sometimes I get an error

```
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
```

The log shows be that the token has been passed in the parameters and I cannot find out why the validation fails. I ma sure that there is no malicious use or anything like that.

Are there any reasons why a CSRF token loses its validity? Maybe it's only valid for a certain time?

Answer (score 1):

CSRF protection in Rails works by storing a random value as a field in the form being submitted, and also in the user session. If the values don't match when a form is submitted, Rails rejects the form submission request.

> If you're using the default cookie session store in Rails, then
> sessions won't expire (until the cookie does). If you're using
> something else (file or DB backed sessions), then yes, if those
> sessions expire, the form submission will fail with a CSRF error.

So if you're using cookie based sessions (the default), check the cookie expiry. If that looks OK, it's probably some other issue.